# Periodic Anderson model vs Anderson impurity model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body, greens-functions, mean-field-theory, strong-correlated

What is the difference between these two models? I would appreciate if the answer could provide me with some useful references from which I can learn these models.

I saw that periodic Anderson model is solved (in infinite dimensions) using the Anderson impurity model (which is the DMFT as far as I understand), but I would like to understand these models in mode detail.

I would also like to learn how is this connected to DMFT? Are there any good books or pedagogical papers that explain these?

Answer (score 5):

**Anderson model**
[Anderson model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_impurity_model) describes an impurity coupled to a Fermi sea. This seemingly simple model contains very rich physics - particularly, it exhibits Kondo effect, which had been extensively studied for several decades, and involves many big names and a variety of techniques (a range of diagrammatic approaches, bosonization/orthogonality catastrophe, Bethe ansatz, density functional theory, etc.). As a consequence vast literature is available on the subject. Perhaps [the review by Bickers](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.59.845) could be a good starting point for further literature search.

Note that another model used for Kondo effect is [Kondo model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kondo_model) - that of a spin coupled to a Fermi sea. In the regime of interest to Kondo physics, Anderson model can be transformed to Kondo model using [Schrieffer-Wolff transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrieffer%E2%80%93Wolff_transformation).

In the last few decades the Anderson model has been extensively used for modeling quantum dots, see, e.g., the series of papers on non-equilibrium transport originating from the publication by [Meir, Wingreen and Lee](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.70.2601) (see also [the paper by this group that used the density functional theory](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature05054))

**Periodic anderson model**
Periodic Anderson model, as its name correctmy suggests, is a series of Anderson impurities arranged on a lattice. It differs from [the Hubbard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard_model) in that in the latter the sites are coupled by tunneling, whereas in the periodic Anderson model they are coupled via the Fermi sea (this is a kind of [RKKY interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKKY_interaction) between magnetic moments). The model is thus interesting for the phase transitions it exhibits, which mix both its Hubbard-like properties (metal-insulator transition), magnetic properties ((anti)ferromagnetic transition), and Kondo physics.

**Remark:** Anderson model is sometimes called *Anderson impurity model* to distinguish it from the model used by Anderson in the context of [*Anderson localization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_localization) (and perhaps other contributions by this fruitful scientist).

Comment: I would add that the periodic Anderson model is interesting also because it is often used to describe heavy-fermion materials.